Azure Devops deploy to AKS suddenly failing with network_error
We have a several pipelines that deploy to 2 AKS clusters which has been working for about 6 months. Suddenly, last Thursday, all the deployments started to fail. The pipeline is set up to delete the last deployment before it deploys the updated code. The AKS cluster is private and the deployment happens from a self-hosted agent machine. Here is what the step looks like
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: KubernetesManifest@1
                  displayName: Delete previous deployment
                  inputs:
                    connectionType: "azureResourceManager"
                    azureSubscriptionConnection: "$(aksServiceConnection)"
                    azureResourceGroup: $(askResourceGroupName)
                    kubernetesCluster: $(aksName)
                    namespace: $(namespaceDv)
                    action: delete
                    arguments: deployment mynamespace-deploy --ignore-not-found=true   

However the pipeline fails with the following error:
##[debug]MSAL - ServicePrincipal - clientSecret is used.
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:52 GMT] : [] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - acquireTokenByClientCredential called
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:52 GMT] : [9a5f7d9c-befc-48a8-aede-4f35e9f59201] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - Building oauth client configuration with the following authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token.
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:52 GMT] : [9a5f7d9c-befc-48a8-aede-4f35e9f59201] : @azure/msal-common@14.12.0 : Info - Sending token request to endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - temporary error code: network_error
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - remaining attempts: 3
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 53442.00 MB out of 68979.00 MB, Memory: Used 521.00 MB out of 11957.00 MB, CPU: Usage 6.34%
##[debug]MSAL - getMSALToken called. force=undefined
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:54 GMT] : [] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - acquireTokenByClientCredential called
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:54 GMT] : [a2b748f6-2067-4bd1-841c-d1c386f57725] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - Building oauth client configuration with the following authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token.
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:54 GMT] : [a2b748f6-2067-4bd1-841c-d1c386f57725] : @azure/msal-common@14.12.0 : Info - Sending token request to endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - temporary error code: network_error
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - remaining attempts: 2
##[debug]MSAL - getMSALToken called. force=undefined
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:56 GMT] : [] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - acquireTokenByClientCredential called
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:56 GMT] : [22e38295-49ce-40c4-b4a5-6d59afb0e24a] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - Building oauth client configuration with the following authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token.
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:56 GMT] : [22e38295-49ce-40c4-b4a5-6d59afb0e24a] : @azure/msal-common@14.12.0 : Info - Sending token request to endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - temporary error code: network_error
##[debug]MSAL - retrying getMSALToken - remaining attempts: 1
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 53442.00 MB out of 68979.00 MB, Memory: Used 521.00 MB out of 11957.00 MB, CPU: Usage 6.16%
##[debug]MSAL - getMSALToken called. force=undefined
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:58 GMT] : [] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - acquireTokenByClientCredential called
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:58 GMT] : [cf0db17c-ccb6-41f1-a3a5-a67c2698a467] : @azure/msal-node@2.9.2 : Info - Building oauth client configuration with the following authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token.
##[debug][Thu, 27 Jun 2024 15:03:58 GMT] : [cf0db17c-ccb6-41f1-a3a5-a67c2698a467] : @azure/msal-common@14.12.0 : Info - Sending token request to endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: CantDownloadAccessProfile
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;source=TaskInternal;]Can't find loc string for key: CantDownloadAccessProfile
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]CantDownloadAccessProfile mycluster-aks Could not fetch access token for Azure. Status code: network_error, status message: Network request failed  

Steps done:

Ensured that client secret is not expired

Logging into the Agent machine, I tested a curl to login.microsoftonline.com using the client secret and it returns a token

Logging into the Agent machine, I tested kubelogin using the client secret and it returns a token

updated kubectl and kubelogin to the latest version


However, the failure remains.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Hi there, Per the $(aksServiceConnection) referenced by the KubernetesManifest@1 task, it should be an ARM service connection, right? Have you tried to click on the Verify button when Editing this service connection in Project settings? By the way, is this service connection authenticating against the same service principal as that you tested with on agent machine? Is it an app registration or a managed identity?

Yes its an ARM service connection. The Verify test works for the service principal Service Connection screen. Yes, used the same account to test from command line as the one that runs the agent machine. The identity is an app registration.

Thanks for the information. May I know if the deployment job running the KubernetesManifest@1 task was referencing any AKS resource under its environment property? If yes, would you double check if the AKS resource is valid in the Pipelines -> Environments?

Finally figured out the issue. Had to add login.microsoftonline.com to the proxy bypass list on the agent machine. Being unable to acquire a token, the agent was unable to move forward. Why the previous state worked but then failed after 6 months is still not understood at the moment. Thats time spent which is never coming back :(

Thanks! We had to create a .proxybypass file in the agent root folder with login.microsoftonline.com in it. The previous state had also been working for months. The initial authentication token was presumably created by an admin account- only when it expired did the service account try to re-authenticate, which fails with the proxy bypass.
